# JsonPath - Extract property by name

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am trying to extract any property name containing "cpu" and "usageRatio" from the following Json using Jayway JsonPath, but so far I have been out of luck.

Checked their documentation and could not find a solution. Any ideas?

To be clear, I would like to extract cpu usage ration for all cpu's in a dynamict fashion (there can be many cores):

```
{
   "entries" : {
      "cpu.0_1.user" : {
         "lastUpdateMicros" : 1493578024979676,
         "value" : 10167446,
         "updateType" : "MOVING_AVERAGE"
      },
      "cpu.0_1.idle" : {
         "value" : 277255191,
         "lastUpdateMicros" : 1493578024979652,
         "updateType" : "MOVING_AVERAGE"
      },
      "disk.usr.usageRatio" : {
         "value" : 0.871294498443604,
         "lastUpdateMicros" : 1493578024990246,
         "updateType" : "BASIC"
      },
      "disk.shared.usedSpace" : {
         "updateType" : "BASIC",
         "lastUpdateMicros" : 1493578024990318,
         "value" : 707563520
      },
      "disk.var.log.availableSpace" : {
         "lastUpdateMicros" : 1493578024990355,
         "value" : 7224614912,
         "updateType" : "BASIC"
      },
      "disk.usr.local.www.guiserverroot.usr.local.www.guiserver.availableSpace" : {
         "value" : 2369658880,
         "lastUpdateMicros" : 1493578024990398,
         "updateType" : "BASIC"
      },
      "cpu.0_0.idle" : {
         "value" : 265264234,
         "lastUpdateMicros" : 1493578024979593,
         "updateType" : "MOVING_AVERAGE"
      },
     "cpu.0_1.usageRatio" : {
         "value" : 0.07,
         "lastUpdateMicros" : 1493578024979635,
         "updateType" : "MOVING_AVERAGE"
      },
      "cpu.0_0.usageRatio" : {
         "lastUpdateMicros" : 1493578024979564,
         "value" : 0.12,
         "updateType" : "MOVING_AVERAGE"
      }
}
```

Yes, I know the Json structure sucks but sadly I don't have access to change it.

/Patrik

Comment: So you're saying you need to be able to select the "value" field of any property whose name contains certain characters, where the properties are completely dynamic?

Comment: Sounds about right. I also need to extract each property name that matches the string.